# Rails model scope with has_many error

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model, scope

I would like to create a scope for only user's that have hosted an appointment that is marked as complete.

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :appointment_hosts, 
           :class_name => "Appointment", 
           :foreign_key => "appointment_hosts_id"

  scope :repeat_customers, -> { includes(:appointment_hosts)
                               .where("appointment_hosts.status=?", "Complete")
                               .references(:appointment_hosts) }
end
```

Appointment.rb

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
       belongs_to :appointment_host, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "appointment_host_id"
end
```

Error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "appointment_hosts"
LINE 1: ...ents"."appointment_host_id" = "users"."id" WHERE (appointmen...
```

Comment: I think your scope is wrong, but I can't understand what you wanna find?

Comment: I want to find all Users that have an Appointment which has a status of Complete

Comment: You're referencing the singular form: `.references(:appointment_host)`. You probably meant `.references(:appointment_hosts)` instead.